# Smallest Cunningham chain of length $4$

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

A Cunningham chain of length $l$ is a sequence of prime numbers $p_i$ such that $p_{i+1} = 2p_i+1$. [This website](http://primes.utm.edu/glossary/xpage/CunninghamChain.html) lists the smallest prime that starts a complete Cunningham chain of length $l$, for $1<l<13$.

In it, they state that the smallest prime for a Cunningham chain of length $4$ is $509$. I disagree with this, since I can find a chain of length $4$ starting at a lower prime:
$$
\{5, 11, 23, 47\}.
$$

Therefore $5$ should be the lowest prime starting a Cunningham chain of length $4$. What am I missing? Or is the website wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chain is not complete. You can include a $2$ at the beginning to make a chain of length $5$. The site isn't claiming that $509$ is the smallest prime that starts a chain of length $4$, they are claiming that it is the smallest prime that starts a *complete* chain of length $4$.